# Skip selecting single cells in column using keyboard shortcuts only

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, selection

I'll try to articulate this as best as I'm able. Using Excel, I need to **select** a couple of cells in a column, **skip** one, then **select** a couple more, then **skip** one, etc. I know there's a keyboard shortcut, but I can't, for the life of me, remember what it is. I've tried **shift+tab+arrow**, **shift+alt+arrow**, **shift+space+arrow**, **shift+ctrl+arrow**, I even tried **shift+left mouse click** (which I'm actually looking to avoid, but that combo didn't work)... I'm quickly running out of possible combinations, and am hoping someone out there can help. TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> for it.

Select the first group of cells, pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> you can use arrows to move without loosing selection, select another range and repeat.

Each range you select need to consist of at least two cells.

Comment: It does work. Kind of new for me this thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the keyboard-shortcuts, but with mouse it would be ctrl click and drag to just select multiple cells.

Also you can write code that can do all kind of things without actually selecting the cells you need.
And if an easy formula doesn't help there is still scripts and filters to help you out.

I'm not sure if this is helpful to you, but I don't see what your reason is to actually use keyboard-shortcuts, so if you can expand your question I might can help in a better way. Also Microsoft itself only mentions selecting (via pointer) as a way to select non-adjacent cells as far as I know.